# Keeping my layout from jumping

Tags: html, css, layout

Take a look at the current site under construction that I'm working on:

http://69.134.44.19:8000/cprod.html?cat=Doughnuts&subp=Sprinkle%20Doughnut

The site is for a virtual business class I'm taking.  Now, if you spam the F5 key, the layout 'jumps' to the correct position.  Now, spamming F5 doesn't make SO 'jump'.  In truth, most sites don't jump.

It kind of makes the site feel odd when going page from page with the 'jump'.  Is there a way to make sure the page has determined the sizes before it displays?  I assume the issue is with the fact that I use quite a lot of percentages with the div sizes.

Comment: `127.0.0.1`? That's different for everyone..

Comment: @RobW ACK!  Woops!  **EDIT** OK, now I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notable styles are defined in an external stylesheet. When your main page is loaded, the CSS files might not be ready, causing the lay-out to look different. When the external resources have finished loading, your lay-out change to the final look.

Comment: So with this in mind, is there a way to solve this issue?  SO has external CSS but it doesn't jump...

Comment: Use the `cache-control` header, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486805/html-cache-control-max-age. Also.. Your CSS files are served with MIME-type `text/html`, which should be `text/css`.

Comment: I'll go change the MIME-type's now.  So, other than that though, it's just the fact that my server is caching the CSS for the client?  Currently, I'm using a very light weight server for testing purposes only.  Is that the *part* of the problem?

Comment: Wait, all of the CSS has the attribute `type="text/css"`.  Where did you see it have `text/html`?

Comment: The **client** should cache the files, and not look back at the server. This can be done by sending the appropriate headers (see previous comment). If you want to see SO's lay-out "jumping", use CTRL+F5. **EDIT**: I saw the `Content-type: text/html` response header when I inspected the network traffic using [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/).

Comment: That's odd, my file marks it as text/css.  It may be my servers doing, I'll go check the supported MIME types.  Anyways, you've been lots of help. +1 and a accept!